# Session Problem in JSP

Tags: java, session, jsp, servlets

I am setting and getting the session attributes on login page, when i logout the page and press the back button it goes to home page again.

Here is my code,

```
::::::::::::::::::::::::::**sessionaction.jsp**::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

<%@page import="java.util.*" %>
<%
    String str = request.getParameter("UserName");
    session.setAttribute("sessUserName", request.getParameter("Password"));
%>

<%
    if (session.getAttribute("sessUserName").equals(""))
    {
        response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");
%>

<%
    }
else
    {
        response.sendRedirect("home.jsp");
    }
%>


::::::::::::::::::::::::::**logout.jsp**::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
<%@page import="java.util.*" %>

<%
//session.invalidate();
session.removeAttribute("sessUserName");
%>

You have logged out. Please
<a href="login.jsp"><b>Login</b></a>
```

Kindly guide me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
if (session.getAttribute("sessUserName") == null)
```

Answer (score 2):

Set Cache Headers

```
response.setHeader("Cache-Control","private, no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
```

Also

if needed meta tags for Cache-Control

Answer (score 1):

Root cause, I believe, is **already suggested by user sje397**(accept his answer), I am only elaborating here. Reason is that your session invalidation is not in sync with the code in your login.jsp.

You are removing the attribute from session which means the below code

```
if(session.getAttribute("sessUserName").equals(""))
```

should be changed to

```
if(session.getAttribute("sessUserName")==null)
```

Others:
The back button might just be displaying the home page from its local cache. Try [disabling the cache](http://www.xyzws.com/JSPfaq/how-to-disable-browser-caching-for-a-specific-jsp/11) and see if it works.